# Non-trivial Functional Dependency of this table

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies

Which non-trivial functional dependencies hold in the following table?
Can anyone explain step by step the rules please?

```
A   B   C
------------
a1  b2  c1    
a2  b1  c6    
a3  b2  c4    
a1  b2  c5    
a2  b1  c3    
a1  b2  c7
```

Comment: I just skimmed the examples in the wikipedia article, but I don't think there are any, or none can be identified by this example, as the values for C are unique. You could say `C -> A`, or `C -> B`, or `AC -> B` or `BC -> A`, but those are rather trivial....

Comment: you can try an online solver to find out the [solution](http://www.schirmeier.com/horst/scripts/functional-dependencies.php?colnames=A+B+C&data=a1++b2++c1++++%0D%0Aa2++b1++c6++++%0D%0Aa3++b2++c4++++%0D%0Aa1++b2++c5++++%0D%0Aa2++b1++c3++++%0D%0Aa1++b2++c7++)

Comment: Also just skimmed the Wikipedia article, and I've identified the following: `A → B` and `C → {A, B}`. Might be far off the mark though...

Comment: @tobias_k According to the Wikipedia article, *trivial* has a specific meaning when it comes to functional dependencies, i.e. the dependent set is a subset of the determinant set.

Comment: @tobias_k Can you explain how to find that please?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Can you explain how to find that please?

Comment: I've read the Wikipedia article but i still have problem in some parts. can you guys please explain me in more details?

Comment: @m.s. Thanks for the link. was so great. Do you know any links or any examples that explained step by step the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with a disclaimer to state that my knowledge of functional dependencies is limited to what was explained in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency), and that I currently don't have the need nor the inclination to study up on it further.

However, since OP asked for clarification, I'll attempt to clarify how I obtained the seemingly correct answer that I posted in the comments.

First off, this is Wikipedia's definition:

> Given a relation *R*, a set of attributes *X* in *R* is said to
>   functionally determine another set of attributes *Y*, also in *R*,
>   (written *X → Y*) if, and only if, each *X* value is associated with
>   precisely one *Y* value; *R* is then said to satisfy the functional
>   dependency *X → Y*.

Additionally, Wikipedia states that:

> A functional dependency FD: *X → Y* is called *trivial* if *Y* is a
>   subset of *X*.

Taking these definitions, I arrive at the following two non-trivial functional dependencies for the given relation:

- ***A → B***
- ***C → {A, B}***

Identifying these was a completely inductive process. Rather than applying a series of rules, formulas and calculations, I looked at the presented data and searched for those constraints that satisfy the above definitions.

In this case:

- ***A → B***
  There are three possible values presented for *A*: *a1*, *a2* and *a3*. Looking at the corresponding values for *B*, you'll find the following combinations: *a1 → b2*, *a2 → b1*, and *a3 → b2*. Or, every value of *A* is associated with precisely one *B* value, conforming to the definition.
- ***C → {A, B}***
  The same reasoning goes for this dependency. In this case, identifying it is a little bit easier as the values for *C* are unique in this relation. In this sense, *C* could be considered as a *key*. In database terms, a [*candidate key*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) is exactly that: a minimal set of attributes that uniquely identifies every tuple.

Undoubtedly, there's a way to mathematically derive the functional dependencies from the data, but for simple cases like this, the inductive process seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, non-trivial functional dependencies in the above table are:

```
 1. A->B
 2. A,C->B
 3. B,C->A
 4. C->A,B
```